# How we can integrate FreeRDP API in our android app to remotely share desktop?

Tags: rdp

How we can integrate FreeRDP Api in our android app to remotely share desktop? Is FreeRDP suppose 1 to many sharing ? I mean that can we share same desktop from multiple android devices in one time.

Thanks in advance.